# How to use Yolo in ROS Noetic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I used ROS Melodic/Ubuntu 18.04, I could use the darknet_ros package from Legged Robotics.  Now I have 'upgraded' to ROS Noetic/Ubuntu 20.04 I cannot find any way to install Darknet and Yolo.

The problem is due to *configuration hell.*  I am using cuda 10.1 and gcc 8.4.0 due to compatibility requirements imposed by other systems.  I have tried so many branches of darknet_ros.  Many of these do not come with a version of darknet, so I have sought that from other github sources.  I can't find anything that works together.  Ubuntu 20.04 uses opencv4.  There is a darknet branch which supports that, but then compiling darknet_ros complains that darknet is missing a file 'art.c'.  If I try other branches of darknet the compiler complains of needing C++11 for opencv *even though the cmake files specify c++11.*

Can anyone point me to a setup that works under Noetic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370728/how-to-use-yolo-in-ros-noetic-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crnewton](https://answers.ros.org/users/59954/crnewton/) on 2021-02-01**:
relevant: https://answers.ros.org/question/369095/getting-yolodarknet_ros-working-in-ubuntu-20-and-ros-noetic/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a usable version.  In [this link](https://github.com/leggedrobotics/darknet_ros/issues/290), bigrobinson gives a procedure for using [this github repository](https://github.com/kunaltyagi/darknet_ros.git).  You must use the opencv4 branch (the procedure is all explained in the original link.  I followed it. It worked !).

That solves getting yolo v3 running in Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS Noetic.  If anyone knows how to use YoloV4 or the pytorch version YoloV5 in Noetic please add pointers as comments !

---

Originally posted by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) with karma: 142 on 2021-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1